# Bootstrap: next button should display next tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement a custom next button into the bootstrap tab navigation.

When clicking on the next-button, the next tab should be displayed as active.
If the last tab is reached it should start with the first tab.

[Bootply snippet](http://www.bootply.com/leROypGiFc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solve your problem

```
$('.next-tab').click(function(e){
  if($('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').hasClass('next-tab')){
    $('.nav-tabs > li').first('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  }else{
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/XYpxMIgink

Answer (score 0):

I Recently needed this functionality and this is what I ended up with:

```js
$('.change-tab').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $nav = $($this.data('target'))
  var $tabs = $nav.find('li');
  var $curTab = $tabs.filter('.active');
  var cur = $tabs.index($curTab);
  if ($this.data('direction') == 'next') var $showTab = cur == $tabs.length - 1 ? $tabs.eq(0).find('a') : $tabs.eq(cur + 1).find('a');
  else var $showTab = cur == 0 ? $tabs.eq($tabs.length - 1).find('a') : $tabs.eq(cur - 1).find('a');
  $showTab.tab('show');
});



// normal tabs code
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

$(function () {
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Content here...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings...</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default change-tab" data-direction="previous" data-target="#myTab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Last</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default change-tab" data-direction="next" data-target="#myTab">Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tabs aren't clickable anymore here.

Comment: @herrh I did not include the regular tab code in my example, sorry.  I added it above so you can see it working with the normal usage

Answer (score 0):

I am using @DelightedD0D provided solution. When the page load, the control stop on the last tab always. If you want to fix this, please update the following function

```
$(function () {
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
})
```

to

```
$(function () {
$('#myTab a:active').tab('show');
})
```

Comment: by using @DelightedD0D code, how to stop it on the last tab? and prevent it to go back to last tab, when clicking Last button on the first tab? any idea?