# How to select bootstrap tabs using "next" button. I have followed other answers but not working

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have below code in asp.net page to show tabs using bootstrap. I can click tabs without any problems. But now I want to select them one by one using a next ">" button. So, when page loads Price_1 is active and when i click ">" price_2 should be selected and so on. Please give me some suggestions.

Code is here 
https://codeshare.io/4SA8A

```
 <style>
     .next-tab {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
                }
    </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

   <script>

        $('.next-tab').click(function (e) {
            if ($('#tabs > .active').next('li').hasClass('next-tab')) {
                $('#tabs > li').first('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            } else {
                $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

   </script>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:none"> 
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Price_1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Price_2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Price_3</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Price_4</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">Price_5</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">Price_6</a></li>
            <li class="next-tab"><a href="">&gt;</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I tried this solution as well but it doesn't work. When I click ">" it is going to homepage in IE and in google chrome its not selecting the next tab and also refreshing the page which I don't want. I think this is because the href tag is empty

```
<li class="next-tab"><a href="">&gt;</a></li>
```

[Bootstrap: next button should display next tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579195/bootstrap-next-button-should-display-next-tab)

Please help.

Comment: Er... Where's your code?

Comment: I tried exactly as in this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579195/bootstrap-next-button-should-display-next-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're including jQuery twice which can cause a conflict, and 1.6.x is too old for Bootstrap 3. Remove the 1.6.x link..

`http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js`

Old jQuery doesn't work: http://bootply.com/gzlsfVTNq9

jQuery 1.9.x or greater works: http://bootply.com/XYpxMIgink#

Comment: Thanks. I removed the line you suggested and it worked. I got that line from W3schools try it editor.

Answer (score 1):

You load the script before the `<a>` tag loads, so the events are not getting bound. Enclose your script this way:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('.next-tab').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#tabs > .active').next('li').hasClass('next-tab')) {
      $('#tabs > li').first('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    } else {
      $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

And also, you need to add the `id="tabs"` here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" style="border-bottom:none">
```

The `$(function () {});` is a short hand code for `$(document).ready(function () {});`. This ensures that the code is executed after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Just tried, now nothing is happening not even postback or refreshes.

Comment: @Akshay See the updated answer above. Don't just blindly copy and paste man. Understand what you do.

Comment: @Akshay Did you see the updated answer to add `id="tabs"`?

Comment: yes..   <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:none">  but same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109017/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-akshay).